# Doing math in a PHP script from SQL DB

Tags: php, number-formatting

So I have a script the is measuring Fuel burned and lbs or loads and driven distance.

So here is the script I have

```
<td><?php ($row['trailerMass']); echo (($row['trailerMass']) * 2.2)."\n"; ?></td>
<td><?php ($row['litresBurned']); echo (($row['litresBurned']) * 0.264)."\n"; ?></td>
<td><?php ($row['distanceDriven']); echo (($row['distanceDriven']) * 0.621)."\n"; ?></td>
```

So I have the trailerMass converting from KGs to lbs and then it is displaying 
29438.2
I would like it to display 2 digits after the .

Then on LitresBurned I have it converting to US gallons and it is displaying like this 
39.62376
I honestly would just like it to display 39.62 But I have tried everything I know of for about a week and wanted some insight figured this is a good place to ask.

Then for distanceDriven that is in KM I am converting it to Miles and it is being displayed like this 180.00306  I would like to figure out the format to only display 180.00

So I guess it would be number_formating but I am having issues. would just like some help

Comment: `number_format(($row['trailerMass']) * 2.2), 2, '.', '');` try that

Comment: why people are not marking answer even they got solution?